# Show all files affected by a commit with git log when given only one file

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to `git log file` and have it show the full commit details, including all files affected by that commit, like `git log --stat=999,999` produces.

For example, `git log --stat=999,999 path/to/file` shows a diffstat of just that one file and if its associated commit had more files in it then it won't show them. I'd like it to show all files of the commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what I think you are looking for with:

```
git log --format=%H $filename | while read x; do git show --stat $x; done
```

or

```
git show --stat $(git rev-list HEAD -- $filename)
```

(These are variations on a theme.)
If you have to deal with historical renames, you may want to use `git log --follow`.

Comment: Nice work. That second one was what I was hoping for.

Comment: Too bad I can't git alias that but it works okay as a bash function: git-log-file () { git show --stat $(git rev-list HEAD -- "${@}") }

Comment: You can shell out in a git alias, so you could do `!bash -c 'git show --stat $(git rev-list HEAD -- \"$@\")' _`.  (eg, either write that directly in a .gitconfig, or execute `git config alias.lg '!bash -c '"'"'git show --stat $(git rev-list HEAD -- "$@")'"'"' _'`